# I can't implement Redirect in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I want to redirect to the home page when some condition returns null or false but the action of Redirect is not triggered.

```
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

if(localStorage.getItem("example") === null || localStorage.getItem("example") === false){
    return <Redirect to="/" />
}
```

I put this code inside in a simple function triggered in one `OnClick` and `componentDidMount()`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Redirect to home page, based on redirect flag that could be changed by using setState in onClickHandler or handleSubmit.

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  handleSubmit () {
    if(localStorage.getItem("example") === null || localStorage.getItem("example") === false){
      return this.setState({ redirect: true });
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to='/'/>;
    }
    return <YourForm/>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Redirect inside render. It is a React Component which renders and then sends the user to the desired path:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class RootPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedOut: false
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoggedOut: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isLoggedOut && <Redirect to="/logout" />}
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Logout</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Log = () => <h1>Logout</h1>;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar" />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={RootPage} />
          <Route exact path="/logout" component={Log} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

When you click on the logout button it will redirect you to the rootPath.

Here is the Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/q9v2nrjnx4

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) in the official docs.

`<Redirect />` should be inside your `render` method if you use a class component. or if you use a function component it should be in what's returned by it.

Example bellow:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

const PrivateComponent = (props) => {
  return(
    localStorage.getItem("example")
      ? <RandomComponent />
      : <Redirect to="/signin" />
  )
}
```